# persistence.xml is not found for Hibernate JPA project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am new to Hibernate JPA. I am using eclipse kepler 4.3.2 and create a simple java project. I am not using maven to compile the project. I am having the below persistence.xml located in the src folder of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" >
    <persistence-unit name="rawsjpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <class>com.mumz.test.hibernatesearch.entitybeans.MHSBookEntityBean</class>
        <class>com.mumz.test.hibernatesearch.entitybeans.MHSBookShelfEntityBean</class> -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Test2@cdn"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rschcdndb1d.nam.nsroot.net)(PORT=1526))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=OSRDD1)))"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="AW"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am having the below sample main program trying to create the EntityManager.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author jp48346
 *
 */
public class TestRawsConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rawsjpa").createEntityManager();
        if(entityManager!=null){
            System.out.println("************* EntityManager is obtained *****************");
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the eclipse project .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="main/resources/META-INF/" kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.2.17.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.17.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jp48346/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

when I am trying to execute the program I am getting the below exception

```
May 26, 2015 8:52:17 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
May 26, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.17.Final}
May 26, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 26, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 26, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named rawsjpa
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at TestRawsConnection.main(TestRawsConnection.java:15)
```

Can anybody please tell me where should I place persistence.xml to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the persistence.xml file should reside in a folder named `META-INF`. If you are using using Maven, put it in `src/main/resources/META-INF` (create the folder if it's not there).

Comment: But I am not using maven so Is it Compulsory to use maven for this to work?

Comment: As he said without maven you should make src -> META-INF -> persistence.xml

Comment: @pL4Gu33 why is it so? could you  please give some links on it? I moved my persistence.xml to resources from src and it is working now I do not understand why?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your IDE option for create a Persistence Unit, and it will be placed on the default location.
If you don't have or don't found that option in your IDE, it's usually on the META-INF folder located in the proyect root folder, like this:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep `persistence.xml` under `META-INF` folder.

In Eclipse, it would be under

```
Project --> WebContent --> META-INF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jboss application server then please make sure the oracle driver exist under the org.hibernate module and having the entry in module.xml file.

Also, right click on project and  set project facet to JPA, it will automatically added your persitence.xml file to META-INF class path of application.

Please share the more information which application server you are using and which oracle driver you are using for connectivity.

Not compulsory to use maven.

cheers.